# How can I correctly do port forwarding on two routers; a Wimax CPE and a D-Link DIR 803?

Tags: router, internet, port-forwarding, wimax

The first router is a Wimax CPE from [BSNL](http://bsnl.in/opencms/bsnl/BSNL/services/mobile/wimax_postpaid_services.html). It is connected to the BSNL towers which enables me to have an Internet connection at my home. The CPE has a LAN port and no other port. But since it does not have WLAN, I unable to create a Wi-Fi network; I want to do that because I want to access Internet on my smart phone as well.

So, I purchased a second router. This is the [D-Link DIR 803](http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DIR-803). I connected the LAN wire form the CPE (the first router) to the WAN port of the D-Link. Then I configured WLAN on the D-Link and created a Wi-Fi network.

Now I can access Internet on all my devices with Wi-Fi.

But no matter what I try, port forwarding does not work. I have tried configuring both the routers individually, but ports are never successfully opened.

I access the first router’s settings page with the address `192.168.1.1`
and the D-Link router’s settings page with the address `192.168.0.1`.
I turned off the windows firewall and my anti-virus, but it didn’t work.
Can anybody tell me what the problem is, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting to do is use Wimax CPE router from BSNL as the main Internet connection and then have the D-Link DIR 803 be the actual main router you connect to, correct?

Your overall instincts and ideas are correct. You *can* connect a device like the Wimax CPE’s LAN port to the WAN port of the D-Link DIR 803. And it *might* work—as you have found—superficially to allow you to share the connection via the D-Link DIR 803 router. But all that is doing is really having the Wimax CPE connect to the D-Link as a full-on second router. Which can cause lots of networking headaches like what you are describing with port-forwarding not working as expected.

What you want to do is disable the core routing capabilities of the Wimax CPE and set it to “bridge mode” so it simply acts like a “dumb” modem with all of the “smarts” being passed to the D-Link DIR 803 router.

I just did a quick Google search and [found this Wimax CPE PDF manual that should be a useful reference](http://www.irancell.ir/portal/Webfiles/wimax/Files/download/Indoor-en.pdf) to explain to you how to set the Wimax CPE into “bridge” mode. But not 100% familiar with this exact device so cannot say for sure; but the general concept is the Wimax CPE should be in “bridge” mode and the D-Link DIR 803 router should handle all of the “heavy lifting” of being a real router. Anything that mixes up the two individual—but connected—routers is just asking for a headache.